# vocabulary and notation for syntactic changes

Tags: syntax, terminology, historical-linguistics, reference-request, diachronic

As a layman I have picked up the terminology and notation for changes in phonology.  But I know very little about diachronic changes in syntax other than that they happen: things like shift from SOV to SVO, or replacement of cases by prepositions.  Can you point me to at least a lesson in the terminology of such changes?

Comment: I would suggest the chapter on historical syntax in Trask's _Historical Linguistics_ (and frankly the rest of the book, too).

Comment: Ah, I found my copy …